# Cardinal number of $U(\Bbb Z / 4 \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/5 \Bbb Z)$ and zero divisors of $\Bbb Z / 45 \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z / 27 \Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem, ring-homomorphism

I'd like to know how many **units** does $ \Bbb Z / 4 \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z / 5 \Bbb Z $ has. And how many **zero divisor** has $ \Bbb Z / 45 \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z / 27 \Bbb Z $. I think I should work with $\Bbb Z /‭1215 \Bbb Z‬$ and $\Bbb Z /‭20 \Bbb Z‬$ using the chinese remainder theorem and that the function 
$$\begin{array}{rccl}
f \colon & \Bbb Z / nm \Bbb Z & \longrightarrow & \Bbb Z / n \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z / m \Bbb Z  \\
&[x]_{nm} & \longmapsto & ([x]_n, [x]_m)
\end{array}\\
$$
where $n,m\in \Bbb Z^+$ are **coprimes** is bijective, but I have no idea about how to do it. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m$ and $n$ be any two positive integers.

Units in the  ring $R=\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$:

$([x]_m,[y]_n)$ is a  unit in $R$ if and only if  ($[x]_m$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ and $[y]_n$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$).

Zero divisors in the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$:

Let $([x]_m,[y]_n)$ be a zero divisor in $R$. Then there exists $([a]_m,[b]_n)\neq 0$ in $R$ such that $([xa]_m,[yb]_n)=([0]_m,[0]_n)$. Thus, all the zero divisors are given by $([x]_m,[y]_n)$ where either $[x]_m$ is zero divisor of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ or $[y]_n$ is a zero divisor of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: So let $\phi$ be the *Euler's phi function*. As $\phi(\Bbb Z / 4 \Bbb Z)=2$ and $\phi(\Bbb Z / 5 \Bbb Z)=4$ then $\phi(\Bbb Z / 4 \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z / 5 \Bbb Z)=8$. Am I wrong, @AnirbanBose?.

Comment: you are right because in general for any $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $gcd (m,n)=1$, $\phi(mn)=\phi(m)\phi(n)$.

Comment: Could you explain that, please? I mean, I have already proved that property, but how are you using it here? $\phi(nm)$ is the Euler's phi function of ring $\Bbb Z /n \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z /m \Bbb Z$?

Comment: I know by chinese remainder theorem the function $$\begin{array}{rccl}
f \colon & \Bbb Z/ nm \Bbb Z & \longrightarrow & \Bbb Z / n \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z / m \Bbb Z\\
&[x]_{nm} & \longmapsto & ([x]_n, [x]_m)
\end{array}$$ is bijective if $gcd(n,m)=1$, but why this implies  $\sharp U(\Bbb Z/ nm \Bbb Z) = \sharp U( \Bbb Z / n \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z / m \Bbb Z)$? @AnirbanBose

Comment: First, I did not use the phi function or the CRT for answering the original question asked. Regarding your last comment: the map $f$ is a ring isomorphism. Therefore, it will take units to units .

Comment: Regarding your second comment, @mug_donut , the phi function by definition counts the number of positive integers less than $n$ which are relatively prime to $n$. Now $[x]_n\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$  is a unit $ \Leftrightarrow$ the ideal generated by $[x]_n$ is the full ring $\Leftrightarrow$ there exists $[y]_n\in   \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ such that $[xy]_n=[1]_n$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $xy-1=nk$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $gcd (x,n)=1$. Thus the phi function equivalently makes sense on positive integers n as well as the ring $ \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**: Let $R,S$ be unital rings. Then prove the identity

$$U(R \times S) = U(R) \times U(S)$$

What are the units of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, what are the units of $\mathbb{Z}$?

For the second question,

$$(x_1,y_1)(x_2, y_2) = (0,0)\iff x_1x_2 = 0 \quad \land \quad y_2y_2 = 0 $$

so finding the zero divisors of $\mathbb{Z}/45\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/27\mathbb{Z}$ also reduces to finding the zero divisors of both rings separately.

Comment: Is there any property that says someting like "In $R=\Bbb Z / n \Bbb Z$, $\forall r \not \in U(R)$ and $r \not = [0]_n$ then $r$ is a zero divisors" @ε-δ?

Comment: You can show that the zero divisors in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are exactly the non-units. Thus an element is either a unit or a zero divisor.